# SQL query: Select all references after a specific item

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following database tables, which hold information about a public transport system:

- Stations (id, name)
- Ride(id, lineName)
- RideStop(rideId, stationId, sequenceNumber, arrivalTime, departureTime)

The RideStop has references to Ride and Station. When ordering the RideStops by sequenceNumber, you get the path of this specific ride.

I need to get the paths from all rides, which leave from a specific station.
I can get the complete paths by executing

```
select * 
from ridestop rs 
where rs.ride in (
  SELECT ride FROM ttm.ridestop where stationid = 8503000
)
```

However, I do not care where a ride came from, only where it goes to.

**Question:**
How can I limit the result to only the remaining part of the rides, beginning at station 8503000?

Comment: If the stations aren't in increasing sequence as you indicate below, how is "the remaining part of the rides" determined?  Especially as you say above that "ordering the RideStops by sequenceNumber" gives you the path of the specific ride...

Comment: I think you confuse the station ID and the sequenceNumber. Station IDs are "random" but the sequenceNumber of RideStop records are an increasing sequence. So if you fetch the RideStop records for a specific station, you get the rides passing that station. Now if you take all RideStop records of those rides which have a sequenceNumber higher as the station 8503000 and order them by sequenceNumber, you get the remaining path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query uses a subquery to the sequence number of each station on the ride.  It then joins this back to the ride stop to choose everything from the ride on or after that sequence number.

```
select rs.*
from ridestop rs join
      (SELECT ride, rs.sequenceNumber
       FROM ride r join
            ridestop rs
            on r.ride = rs.ride
       where stationid = 8503000
      ) r
      on rs.ride = r.ride and
         rs.sequenceNumber >= r.sequenceNumber
order by rs.ride, rs.sequenceNumber
```

Comment: I think it's the right direction, but this query returns a lot of dublicates. Seems like it multiples each record by it's sequencNumber (ridestop 4 of line X appears 4 times)

Comment: No doubt . . . the join in the subquery is supposed to be on ride and ridestop, not ridestop and ridestop.  I fixed that issue.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. If the data from the ride table is not required, the inner subquery can be replaced by directly joining onto the ridestop table.

Answer (score 0):

If the StationId is in Increasing sequence .. the below query works

```
SELECT *
FROM   ridestop rs
WHERE  rs.ride IN (SELECT ride
                   FROM   ttm.ridestop
                   WHERE  ( stationid = 8503000
                            AND stationid > 8503000 ))
```

Comment: That would be nice, but stations are not necessarily in increasing sequence. The lines criss-cross the station network

Comment: Should that be "WHERE (stationid=8503000 OR stationid > 8503000 ))"??